# Is this the correct function to ensure that some of the files my app is creating aren't visible to the end user?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using the following line of code in flutter/dart to make sure that the files that my app creates here aren't visible to the end user. These files have uid's for names and are crucial for the app to operate so I don't want a user to be able to delete them. Am I using the correct function here?

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is your best bet. But it's still the users phone and if she is clever enough, anything can be removed (jailbroken, rooted, etc..)

The idea is that only the app can access files there. On Android it returns an internal system-wide folder with a specific folder within that only your app can write to. No other app or user can.

If UIFileSharingEnabled is activated in the Info.plist file for an app, then the user can delete files. Other than that, I think the same applies for iOS phones, that the sandboxed environment with the returned directory only is accessible by the app itself and not the user.